# StackExchange is not writing data in realtime

Tags: redis, stackexchange.redis

I have a situation here...i am using stackexchange.redis client to set and get.
When i set and try to get the same key value right after it, it is failing to retrieve the data when it is under heavy load. How can i make sure the data is getting written and committed when i do a HSET.

Any help here is highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you show the code you are using?

Comment: It's a simple hset and then hget

Comment: Are you using an asynchronous call?

Comment: No I am not I am using synchronous fire and forget call for setting data in redis

Comment: I don't think that "fire and foget" waits for the command to be executed.  Use regular synchronous execution and it should work.

Comment: can you please provide an example like some code snippet